# Cross-platform implementation of GNU tools? (Preferably Java)

Tags: gnu, cross-platform

I'd like to have GNU tools available on multiple platforms, behaving the same.
I know there are ports, like http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/, but they are different from what's supported by the linux versions.

Doesn't necessarily have all tools, I'm looking for some basic like

- wget
- sed
- ls
- tee
- grep
- ps
- etc.

All my development revolves around Java, thus I have Java on every machine no matter of the platform. Therefore, I'd prefer implementation Java.

So I tried to find GNU tools implemented in Java, but can't find any such project.

Does anybody know about such?

(PS: Not Apache Ant, I want it for the command line)

Comment: Of course they're different. The underlying OS is different. Changing the language used won't fix that.

Comment: No it wont, but at least there could be one implementation which would work the same on all OS's (same input, same output format)

Comment: But you're right - **updated**.

Answer (score 3):

Some basic unix commands are implemented here: http://www.unix4j.org

Note that only text-processing related commands are available and the implementation is not really like GNU tools --- but maybe it helps anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't. gnu tools tend to be fairly low level and small, and more importantly, coded by old school unix hackers, to whom C is the language that god himself wrote (many disagree, some say its lisp, other python) - there are only a handful of common coreutils (what you call gnu tools)  implimentations, and all are c.

It is simply the way it is. However, coreutils should work mostly the same, unless the developer chose to change the syntax.